# Chaotic distribution of rows by category

Tags: c#, task

There is a big list of lines. I divide it into several lists and run the method "SpellChecker" for correcting spelling errors in strings. Next, I run a method "SearchKeyWordsInString" that should correlate these strings in accordance with keywords in some categories. BUT, the output is not the correct match of the lines and categories.
I have a list of strings, I divide this list into several sublists, and run tasks for each sublist. The problem appears when, after launching a task with a spell checker method, I, in the continuation of this task, launch a method for categorizing these lines. There is no such situation if I do not share the source lines and run in one task.

```
        List<string> strListExcel = null;

        var excel = new Excel();
        excel.OpenFileNPOI(pathAndNameFile);
        excel.ReadFileNPOI(out strListExcel);
        excel.CloseFileNPOI();
        var stringUnderList = new List<List<string>>();

        int index = 0;
        int countProcess = Environment.ProcessorCount * 1;
        int countStr = strListExcel.Count;
        int count = countStr / countProcess;

        while (true)
        {
            stringUnderList.Add(new List<string>());
            stringUnderList[index].AddRange(strListExcel.Skip(index * count).Take(count));
            index++;
            if (index == countProcess + 1)
                break;
        }

        var tasks = new List<Task<List<DataCategory>>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringUnderList.Count; i++)
        {
            var localStringUnderList = stringUnderList[i];
            Task<List<DataCategory>> task = Task.Run(() => Text.SpellChecker(localStringUnderList)).ContinueWith(t => Text.SearchKeyWordsInString(t.Result));

            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        var dataCategoryList = new List<DataCategory>();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringUnderList.Count; i++) //count task = count stringUnderList
            _dataCategoryList.AddRange(tasks[i].Result);
```

Comment: A [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results would be awesome.

Comment: Instead of full code base if you give us input, expected output and specific code then it will be more helpful

Comment: You might be able to simplify this using a Parallel.ForEach loop--> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar The problem as I understand it in the streams. Using ContinueWith

Answer (score 2):

Your code results in some of the last lines not being processed, when the remainder of `countStr / countProcess is` not `0` `(countStr % countProcess != 0)`.

Change

```
if (index == countProcess + 1) 
  break;
```

into

```
if (index == countProcess + 1) {
  stringUnderList[index].AddRange(strListExcel
    .Skip(index * count)
    .Take(countStr % countProcess));

  break;
}
```

Comment: Another approach might be to use something like `MoreLinq`'s `Batch` method.